# D3 - Drawing a path between DOM elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm creating a parallel coordinates chart. Each circle is a particular brand, and every brand has one circle in each column:

[image]

When the user hovers over a circle, I would like to draw a path connecting that circle to the other three circles of the same brand. The issue is that the X position of the circles is random, so I have to draw the line using the circle's modified cx value (and not the data).

Conveniently, I have all four brand circles grouped in their own g elements:

```
<g class="line-group">
    <circle r="5" cx="340.48700997553686" cy="0" data-brand="Brand X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="916.9181438059958" cy="59.347826086956466" data-brand="Brand X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="1589.2772695723352" cy="229.1306884480747" data-brand="Brand X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="2272.275506967826" cy="0" data-brand="Brand X"></circle>
</g>
```

I can grab the elements, and group the coordinates in a way d3.line() likes, but it makes one line that connects every point.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
               .interpolate('basis');

var circles = d3.selectAll('.line-group').selectAll('circle'),
          circleCoords = [];

      circles.forEach( function(d) {
        console.log(circles);
        for ( i = 0; i < d.length; i++ ) {
          var cx = d3.select(d[i]).attr('cx'),
              cy = d3.select(d[i]).attr('cy');

          circleCoords.push([cx, cy]);
        }
      });

      lineGroup.append('path')
             .attr({
               'd' : line( circleCoords )
             });
```

How do I structure this so I can grab the cx and cy values of each circle group (the four circles of the same brand inside of g.line-group)?

I probably have to make a custom d attribute, something like this (pseudocode):

```
path.attr('d', function(d) { 
                  return 'M ' + /* cx of circle 1 */ + ' ' + /* cy of circle 1 */ + 
                    ' L ' + /* cx of circle 2 */ + ' ' + /* cy of circle 2 */ + 
                    ' L ' + /* cx of circle 3 */ + ' ' + /* cy of circle 3 */ + 
                    ' L ' + /* cx of circle 4 */ + ' ' + /* cy of circle 4 */ + ' Z';
                })
```

I believe all the pieces are there, I just can't seem to find a way to put it together correctly. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Added line definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You has the wrong selection (I can't see your line definition, don't forget it):

```
var svg = d3.selectAll("svg")
var circles = svg.selectAll('.line-group').selectAll("circle"),
// or var circles = svg.selectAll('.line-group > circle'),

          circleCoords = [];

      circles.forEach( function(d) {
        for ( i = 0; i < d.length; i++ ) {
          var cx = d3.select(d[i]).attr('cx'),
              cy = d3.select(d[i]).attr('cy');

          circleCoords.push([cx, cy]);
        }
        console.log(circleCoords);  
      });

      var line = d3.svg.line()

      svg.append('path')
             .attr({
               'd' : line( circleCoords )
             });
```

[Here the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/uobpp0La/)

Don't forget styles.
You need to identify each '.line-group' or D3 will select all '.line-group' class, may adding id attribute.-

In your case you have multiple "Brands", like so:

```
<svg>
<g class="line-group">
    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="110" data-brand="Brand-X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="30" cy="120" data-brand="Brand-X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="150" cy="30" data-brand="Brand-X"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="290" cy="40" data-brand="Brand-X"></circle>
</g>

<g class="line-group">
    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" data-brand="Brand-Y"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="30" cy="20" data-brand="Brand-Y"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="150" cy="130" data-brand="Brand-Y"></circle>
    <circle r="5" cx="290" cy="140" data-brand="Brand-Y"></circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

you need to refactory your code:

```
var svg = d3.selectAll("svg")
var circles = svg.selectAll('.line-group').selectAll("circle"),
          circleCoords = [];
var line = d3.svg.line()

// circles.length give you .line-group's count or brand's count:

   for (j=0; j<circles.length; j++) {
       circles[j].forEach( function(d) {     // forEach brand draw a line
          var cx = d.getAttribute('cx'),
              cy = d.getAttribute('cy');
          circleCoords.push([cx, cy]);
       })
       svg.append('path')
          .attr({ 'd' : line( circleCoords )  })
          .attr("id","id_"+j);
       circleCoords = [];
   };
```

[Here's the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/2n3en2oa/)

Comment: If I add a second line-group (for Brand Y), this only creates one path (connecting all the circles for Brand X and Brand Y together). How can I make it so Brand X and Brand Y each have their own separate lines? See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uobpp0La/7/

Comment: Yeap. You still need select the correct series. Thats why must define a unic ID for each series. You could use data-brand attribute

Comment: How would you recommend doing that? I'm trying something like: `var allBrandIDs = d3.set( studyData.map( function(d) { return d.brand_id; } ) ).values();` and then `allBrandIDs.forEach( function(d) { var circles = $('circle').find("[data-brand='" + d + "']"); });`

Comment: You could made multiple small selections or one big and then slice it as you convenience.